# Ansible: variable parameters in modules

Tags: docker, ansible

Is there a way to add a list of parameters to a module from a predefined variable?

For instance, I might have the following vars defined:

```yaml
common_keys_core:
  networks:
    - network1
  restart: always

common_keys_apps:
  networks:
    - network1
    - proxy1
  restart: unless-stopped

common_keys_media:
  networks:
    - network2
    - proxy1
  restart: "no"
```

And a docker container like this:

```yaml
- name: Launch traefik container
  docker_container:
    name: traefik
    image: 'traefik:latest'
    state: started
    <insert common_keys_core here>
    ...
```

As outlined in the example above, I'd like to insert the `common_keys_core` variable as parameters for the docker container.
I have many different containers that require different sets of parameters that can by grouped by core, apps or media. The example I gave is just a simplified version to illustrate my situation.

Docker has a way of doing this using extension fields as follows:

```yaml
    
  traefik:
    <<: *common-keys-core
    container_name: traefik
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Docker has a way of doing this using extension fields

This is actually not docker-compose specific. It's a yaml feature called [Merge Key Language-Independent Type](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html). docker compose just added a way to define those in specific extension fields (starting with x-) that it will simply ignore at parse time so you can reuse them wherever you wish.

You can use the same feature in ansible **as long as you define the anchor and the use of the alias in the same yaml file**

Note that the keys you merge can be overridden where you use them. So your above example could be simplified as follow (pseudo untested playbook)

```yaml
---
- name: pseudo example to use merge key syntax
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    docker_defaults: &ddef
      networks:
        - network2
        - proxy1
      state: started
      restart: unless-stoped

  tasks:
    - name: container using defaults
      docker_container:
        <<: *ddef
        name: traefik
        image: 'traefik:latest'

    - name: container we don't restart
      docker_container:
        <<: *ddef
        name: container1
        image: 'traefik:latest'
        restart: no

    - name: container we don't restart with alternative networks
      docker-container:
        <<: *ddef
        name: container3
        image: 'hello-world:latest'
        restart: no
        networks:
          - anOtherNetwork
```